# Software store recenty started wanting to install updates. How to stop?

Tags: unity, updates, software-center

Using Ubuntu 19.10 with unity desktop.  For years using Ubuntu software updater has taken care of the updates.  For the last month or so software store/centre has been pushing notifications also about updates.

I might have use the software store updater once in the past when also installing something/or looking.

Does anyone know how to prevent or change back software store from notifying about updates.

Would prefer just having software updater handle updates, not both.  Have look a bit at software store settings and did google search, but did not find anything useful.

Comment: do not fight it .. ubuntu rolls out a new release every 6 months .. in April and October so its natural owners of packages are pushing out updates .. I suggest you add this to your file ~/.bashrc    `alias doit='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`   then to run updates from a terminal issue  `doit`  ... updates are part of the bargan ... at least linux has really polished the process especially in comparision to other OS's .. of course if you really must pin a specific package to a certain release or to skip its updates you can put a package on hold `sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>`

Comment: Not fighting the updates.  I like software updater program to handle them.  I don't want the software store/centre to handle them

Comment: @Scott Stensland  If you read the post it mentions I want software updater to handle updates, but not the software store/centre, with keeping software store just for installing programs.